# "for" loop getting skipped/doesn`t work. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, database, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, fetch-api

I'm fetching "ingredient" objects. When i try to iterate through them, "for" loop just getting skipped. Probably my fault(not used to js), but i cant find it.

```js
async function fetchIngredients() {
  let response = await fetch('/Ingredients/GetAll');
  let jsonResult = await response.json();

  console.log(jsonResult);
  return jsonResult;
}

let ingredients = fetchIngredients();

async function displayIngredients(ingredients) {
  let ingredientsContainer = document.getElementById("ingredients-container");

  for (var i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i++) {
    //The loop <<<
  }
}

displayIngredients(ingredients)
```

Here's the object i'm getting:

[image: The object]

Comment: `fetchIngredients()` is async. You invoke `displayIngredients()` *before* the `ingredients` array has been filled.

Comment: `fetchIngredients()` is an async function. That means it does not return a value but a promise. In order to get to the value you need to chain it with a `.then(ingredients=> ... )` method to start some action on the expected result.

Comment: You're trying to eat your pizza before it's been delivered.